# Using SQL to count number of matches in JSON?

Tags: sql, json, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

Here's an example table:

```
id, json_txt
1, [5,18,23,50]
2, []
3, [4,5,12,18,22]
4, [18,22,50]
5, [3,12,70]
```

I want to get the sum of the number of matches from row 3's `json_txt` in the other rows.

Here's what the counts should come out to for each row:

```
1 - 2 matches (5 and 18)
2 - 0 matches
3 - 5 matches (it's the row being searched for)
4 - 2 matches (18 and 22)
5 - 1 match (12)
```

This is as far as I've managed to get:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(json_txt, '[4,5,12,18,22]', '$')
```

But that's only finding the rows with matches, not counting the number of matches in each row :/

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: @Nick 10.3.17-MariaDB-1:10.3.17+maria~xenial

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `information_schema.tables` is used for row generation in order to determine index values as the second arguments for `JSON_EXTRACT()` function along with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function which is available for DB version 10.2+, and `JSON_LENGTH()` function is used to determine the array with maximum length in order to compare every elements within each arrays with the array having id value equals to 3 :

```
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT t.id, JSON_EXTRACT(json_txt, CONCAT('$[', rn - 1, ']')) AS elm
   FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1) AS rn
           FROM information_schema.tables) i
          CROSS JOIN tab t
          WHERE rn <= (SELECT MAX(JSON_LENGTH(json_txt)) FROM tab)
)
SELECT CONCAT( id,' - ',COUNT(id), ' matches ', GROUP_CONCAT(elm)) AS "Result"
  FROM t
 WHERE elm IN ( SELECT elm FROM t WHERE id = 3 )
 GROUP BY id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=ef441848b156027e003de102b0d6caa1)</kbd>